# wordpress - unique theme for different pages

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I am trying to build a custon website based on it. I know some php and quite good html \ css \ js. I wanted to know if it's possible to set a uinque theme for different pages?

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically with the header.php files in your theme.

I'd recommend using the Carrington theme framework (http://carringtontheme.com/ - download JAM to just get a blank theme that you can populate). With this framework you can very easily change template files according to page, author, category, tag and other attributes. So you could drop in a different header template that loads different CSS depending on page slug.

I wouldn't go as far as to load separate themes, but if you really want to go that route then you should do child themes and put a filter on `option_current_theme` so that you can programmatically control the assignment of themes to individual resources.