# How Can I Apply a WordPress Child Theme to Only Some Pages and Not the Whole Site?

Tags: wordpress

I've got a WordPress child theme called Kid based on the Suffusion theme.

The Kid theme just changes the content div's width to 640px. I want to apply the Kid theme to only some pages and not to others.

How do I apply a child theme to only one page and not to the whole site?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

When you edit a page, on the righthand side underneath "Page Attributes", you can choose a different template to apply to that page only.

If on the other hand, by "pages" you mean posts that flow to page 2, page 3 etc.. you may want to take a look at this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826480/wordpress-unique-theme-for-different-pages)

**EDIT:**

Okay, I follow you now.  You are going to need to create a new page template in your child theme.  Then, you can follow the above directions to select that new template.  [Here](http://www.chipbennett.net/2010/11/01/oenology-how-to-create-a-child-theme-and-a-custom-page-template/) is a good reference on how to create a new page template in your child theme.

Hope this helps,

John

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your message. I really appreciate it. When I look under page attributes, I see a number of different options. But, I don't see "Kid" which is the child theme of Suffusion that I made. If I click Themes in the left column, "Kid" is there. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you a push in the right direction.  For what it's worth, I also use Suffusion on one of my blogs and have really been impressed with the amount of work that went into it's development.  Enjoy.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for the help. I think that I'm getting closer. I'm following the tutorial you linked to. But, I'm having some problems. In the section titled "Adding Custom Class to the HTML <body> tag", I'm a bit confused as there is no body tag in Suffusion's page.php file. If I select my child template and then select my new "Wide Middle Column" template under Page Attributes, I don't see a change in the page. I don't think that I've changed the file I named wideMiddleColumn.php correctly. It's a copy of page.php, but I'm not sure what change I need to make. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with child themes, but another method you can use is making page-specific template files in Wordpress themes.

I would recommend duplicating the page.php file in the child theme and renaming it page-"slug".php or page-"id".php - "slug" being the part at the end of the permalink, or "id" being the id number of the page. This is the template file hierarchy, which you can find out more about [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display).

This is where my lack of experience with child themes will show, but I think you can then remove the page.php from the child template, and it will use the parent's page.php file for all pages except for that specific one. Not 100% sure on this last part though.